# how to rename the rows of a column extracted from row names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have added a new column to my data frame by assigning **row names** as a **column**, and I have renamed the column **"Stations"**. The problem is that rows of the new column contain character names with a **set of numbers** representing row numbers, and I want to keep only **row names** as **character** names in my new column and delete the **set of numbers (row numbers)**.

*Therefore, anyone can help to assign row names as a column by only keeping digits representing row names as characters without row numbers, or renaming all rows in **Stations's** column by deleting all the last digits representing row numbers*.

```
> colnames(myDF)[1] <- "Stations"
> head(myDF)
                 Stations year month monthly_precip_sum monthly_precip_avg
JPS6306031.1 JPS6306031.1 1998     1               20.5         0.66129032
JPS6306031.2 JPS6306031.2 1999     1              105.0         3.38709677
JPS6306031.3 JPS6306031.3 2000     1               27.7         0.89354839
JPS6306031.4 JPS6306031.4 2001     1              269.6         8.69677419
JPS6306031.5 JPS6306031.5 2002     1                0.0         0.00000000
JPS6306031.6 JPS6306031.6 2003     1                2.4         0.07741935
```

Comment: So, for example, from `JPS6306031.1 JPS6306031.1`, what exactly do you want to keep?

Comment: You could use pattern replacement like `gsub(pattern = "\\.\\d+$", replacement = "", x = myDF$Stations)`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, for example, from `JPS6306031.1 JPS6306031.2`, I want to keep `JPS6306031 and JPS6306031`, and delete the last digit next to the `.` .

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

If the aim is to "renam[e] all rows in `Stations`'s column by deleting all the last digits representing row numbers", which the OP explains in comments are those digits occurring after the `.`, then this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Stations = gsub("(.*?)\\.\\d+", "\\1", Stations))
```

Comment: The two chunks didn't work for me, it deleted all the number digits. what  I want to delete is only the digit next to `.` such as `.1 .2 .3 .4 .5`, and keep the rest of the digit numbers.

Comment: Please check edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your Station names are the same length as the example you provided, you could try this (using the `stringr` package):

```
myDF$Stations = stringr::str_sub(myDF$Stations, 1, 10)
```